# Get the most recent record from TableB that is older than the record of TableA

Tags: mysql

.. where Table_A is:

CODE, DATE_A

and TABLE_B is:

CODE, DATE_B

AND Where Table_A.CODE = Table_B.CODE

in MySQL 5.5.  Which is the most efficient way please?  Both tables' Primary keys are a composite of the only two fields I have provided (for simplicity's sake).

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.date_b
        from tableb b
        where b.code = a.code and
              b.date_b < a.date_a
        order by b.date_b desc
        limit 1
       ) as date_b
from tablea a;
```

This retrieves the date, and will best use an index on `tableb(code, date_b)`.  To get the rest of the fields, join `tableb` back into the query.

Edit:

To get the rest of the row, you can do this:

```
select *
from (select a.*,
             (select b.date_b
              from tableb b
              where b.code = a.code and
                    b.date_b < a.date_a
              order by b.date_b desc
              limit 1
             ) as date_b
      from tablea a
     ) a join
     tableb b
     on b.code = a.code and b.date_b = a.date_b;
```

Although MySQL will materialize the subquery, this is probably still faster than using a `group by`, which is another alternative.  You could also write the query as:

```
select *
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.code = b.code
where not exists (select 1
                  from tableb b2
                  where b2.code = b.code and
                        b2.date_b > b.date_b
                 );
```

It is possible that this would perform better than my original query.

Comment: Okay, that looks good but can I use that in-line method to retrieve more than one field from Table_B, or am I limited to just one (b.date_b  in this case)?

Comment: With a nested `select` (`select` within a `select`), you can only choose one value.

Comment: Okay, perhaps I was being overly simplistic for the example, but I need to return the whole row of Table_B

Comment: Could you explain how you would join the rest of Table_B to get the rest of it's row please?

Comment: Hi, thanks for adding. The second query now takes an age to run (although it's subquery works really fast.)  The third "not exists" example looks like it will return ALL 'younger' records instead of just one - I haven't tried it though yet.

Comment: @user157109 . . . No, the third returns only the most recent record.  It is saying "Get me records from table b where there is no record with the same code and a larger date".